# How to know maximum speed capacity harddrive I/O

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I want to know maximum speed capacity from my harddrive.

if I use the tool, the tool say i am using 3 MB/s I/O. Is that too much already? Am I at the limit?

How maximum speed capacity from my harddrive, I can use. How do I know that I am not using too much IO

what tool is used to know that?

In linux we can use iostat

What can I use at windows?

We do not need to know how much IO we uses. 3/MB/s is not information we need. We need to know whether if we uses 3MB/s hard disk speed, for example, we want to know whether it's 50% or 100% of hard disk power.

Comment: What type of drive is this? SATA? SAS? SSD? Also, 3MB/s is not IO, it is disk throughput. I/O is calculated by operations per second, either reads or writes, and do not directly correspond with the disk throughput.

Comment: What's the typical max out speed for all those?

Comment: It's the drive in Azure microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for getting an approximate percentage, divide the manufacture declared speed by the measured one, which you have in different tests/situations(even simple reading\writing).